# Can I set min and max attribute for a date input in jsonschema-form lib?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, jsonschema

I'm using [jsonschema-form](https://github.com/mozilla-services/react-jsonschema-form) lib and I would like to set a min and max date in my input field. As explained in [W3C documentation](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_min.asp), in HTML5 min and max are attributes of input element.

The JsonSchema I'm using is very simple:

```
{
  "title": "Date and time widgets",
  "type": "object",
  "properties": {
    "native": {
      "title": "Native",
      "type": "object",
      "properties": {
        "date": {
          "type": "string",
          "format": "date"
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

The UISchema is:

```
{
  "alternative": {
    "alt-date": {
      "ui:widget": "alt-date"
    }
  }
}
```

Can I set min and max attribute for a date input in the jsonschema-form lib? If so, how can do it?

Answer (score 0):

I just bumped into the same challenge and I agree this would be a nice capability. It looks like there is an [active issue for adding support of validation: format[Exclusive](Minimum|Maximum)](https://github.com/json-schema-org/json-schema-spec/issues/116) in a future draft of JSON Schema.

Meanwhile I plan to tackle this by by adding a small amount of JavaScript to set the attributes directly on the generated input elements, using either the generated id or a [custom class](https://github.com/mozilla-services/react-jsonschema-form#custom-css-class-names).